# Rails: duplication of session does not prevent from overwriting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have following variables:

```
@schema = session[:schema]
schema_mod = @schema.dup
```

schema_mod is modified in a function

```
db_query(schema_mod)
```

My problem is that `@schema` gets as well as `session[:schema]` modified.

How can I prevent the modification of a `@schema`?

Answer (score 0):

Porblem with `dup` is it creates a shallow copy.

I suggest you use `deep_dup` [(doc)](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_dup)

```
schema_mod = @schema.deep_dup
```